# USB Input periferics not detected. How can I solve this problem?

Tags: sound, usb, keyboard, mouse, microphone

I'll be straight forward: I have a laptop (ASUS TUF GAMING FX-505DT) and it has 3 ports for USB-A in which I installed:

1. Mouse
2. USB HUB
3. External SSD

The second port seems to work fine, but the problem appears only when I use more ports from the USB HUB. I need to install the Graphic Tablet, Microphone, Keyboard and one for Data Transfer (in total 4).

Whenever I enter a call (for instance on Discord), Mouse and External SSD work fine, but the problem is with the second port: the Microphone works, but when I type on the Keyboard, my keys are being pressed without me holding them! What is even stranger is that, when I removed the Tablet from the HUB, my Keyboard worked again just fine.

Does anybody have any suggestions? Is there a problem specifically in Ubuntu related to the limitation of ports or something like that? Or maybe is it just my laptop? Is there any software I could use to work around it a bit?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, I guess perhaps not an Ubuntu problem, USB v2 limit 2.5Watt (5V, 500mA) v3 limit 4.5Watt (5v, 950mA) etc. Your USB hub must be powered auxiliary in the case they exceed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It helped me a lot!